# How to prevent `Text is read-only` when in minibuffer

Tags: key-bindings, minibuffer

> It's about deleting minibuffer input without trying to also delete some of the minibuffer prompt (which is read-only).

When I do `C-x C-f` for `find-file` and delete all the way of the given path. Now, I keep seeing `Text is read-only` warning message in the minibuffer.

Is it possible to prevent this warning message and let minibuffer remain as `Find file:`  text?

---

```
Find file: /home/alper/foder/  ;; Pressing C-h to remove all characters
Find file:
           ^ Here when I press C-h one last time
```

I am seeing `Text is read-only`.

Comment: I think I just do `C-a C-k` to go to the beginning of the file name, and then to delete all of it. But, your experience will depend on whether you use any of the common completion helpers (s.a. Ido or Helm), because they handle this situation differently.

Comment: In naitive bash, in some cases I get used to do `C-h` and bash shell remains as it is. I actuall use `ido-find-file` which has the same issue.

Comment: The question (apparently) has nothing particular to do with `C-x C-f`. It's about deleting minibuffer input without trying to also delete some of the minibuffer prompt (which is read-only).

Comment: @Drew In minibuffer, could we suppress that warning message?

Comment: For me, `C-h` doesn't do anything in Ido mode. I understand that this was supposed to be the "select all" action, right? As in, `C-x h`? In which case, again, Ido doesn't do anything. In Ido, `Backspace` removes one path fragment, pressing it a few times will delete the whole path. Alternatively, you may press `C-f` again to escape Ido completion entirely.

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention I binded `C-h` to delete char as `'backward-delete-char`. I do not want to escape the Ido completion entirely, just if I do `'backward-delete-char` when there is no char left, I just do not want to see `Text is read-only` warning message

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the following function `backward-delete-char-stop-at-read-only` to the key of your choice (maybe <kbd>C-h</kbd>, but that binding overrides the default help key-binding).
The function is essentially `backward-delete-char` but stops before deleting read-only text. No indication is given if the function is ineffective (as you want it).

```el
(defun backward-delete-char-stop-at-read-only (n &optional killflag)
  "Do as `backward-delete-char' but stop at read-only text."
  (interactive "p\nP")
  (unless (or (get-text-property (point) 'read-only)
          (eq (point) (point-min))
          (get-text-property (1- (point)) 'read-only))
    (setq n (min (- (point) (point-min)) n))
    (setq n (- (point) (previous-single-property-change (point) 'read-only nil (- (point) n))))
    (backward-delete-char n killflag)))
```

You can bind that function to <kbd>C-h</kbd> in the minibuffer by the following form:

```el
(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "C-h") #'backward-delete-char-stop-at-read-only)
```

Comment: This is smart, but I was not able to make it work during `ido-find-file`. The way I set binding is: `(global-set-key (kbd "C-h") 'backward-delete-char-stop-at-read-only)`

Comment: Your solution brings another question. // Can we also stops before deleting `/` character? (`Find file (./): ~/.emacs.d/` C-h won't remove `/` and stops ). I was trying to act in `find-file` most like I was in a shell, where I can only remove the entered characters.

Comment: @alper I appended an instruction how to define the key binding.

Comment: I have added your updated solution but still I am seeing `Text is read-only`in ido-search :( I am having same issue in using `emacs -Q` too

Comment: @alper It works for me with `GNU Emacs 27.1.90` and option `-Q`. I copy the code inclusive the binding definition from the answer into the scratch buffer, evaluate it there and call `M-x ido-find-file`. There are no warnings anymore when point bumps into the read-only text while using `C-h` repeatedly.

Comment: Please note that I am using v26.3. I am still seeing `Test is read-only` text :( Please see my simple init file: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/c4eae26e3bd77433136efeba644bfda5 . I am not sure what's going on wrong. The way I tested: `emacs -q -nw -l ~/emacs_q_base.el test.py`

Comment: Could it be related the emacs version that it does not work on my end?

Comment: @alper You could use `M-x edebug-defun` on `backward-delete-char-stop-at-read-only` and see what is going on when you press `C-h` in the minibuffer.

Comment: `backward-delete-char-stop-at-read-only` works fine, just `C-h` does not runs  it in the minibuffer.

Comment: @alper By accident, I have an Emacs 26.3 available for testing. I put only the stuff from my answer into a file `/temp/init.el` and run `emacs26 -Q -l /temp/init.el`. Under this condition the behavior is like I described in my answer.

Comment: I was able to run as `emacs -nw -Q -l /temp/init.el` since I am in terminal but I am still facing with the same issue

Comment: FWIW I tested this solution on Emacs 28.0.50 (built on commit `d672d576ff6c3ac3c7ee1fa4db13c7e0a4974aa3`) and it works fine: the message does not appear.